# Android - When open google maps my map on my application disappears

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm opening google maps from my app to show the route from one point to another, but when I return to my app the map is not there (the map is in a Fragment). I expected that when I go back to my app the map remain there.

My app at beggining[image: The map is there]
When return from google maps [image: The map disappears]

This is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewPerfilPersona"
    android:src="@drawable/perfil_persona_b"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewClientName"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewClientName"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/ClientName"
    android:id="@+id/textViewClientName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPerfilPersona"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/TimeLeftRequest"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTimeLeft"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewClientName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCar"
    android:src="@drawable/car"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTypeCar" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/TypeCar"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTimeLeft"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/I_need"
    android:id="@+id/textViewI_need"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTire"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewCar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewCar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewCar"
    android:src="@drawable/tire"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewI_need"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewCar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewCar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewI_need" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/ClientLocation"
    android:id="@+id/textViewLocation"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewI_need"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewI_need"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewI_need"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="pathGoogle"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewLocation"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewTire"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewTire"
    android:src="@drawable/map"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewLocation"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewTire"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewTire"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewLocation" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonCheck"
    android:src="@drawable/check"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="requestCheckButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewTypeCar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/WaitResponse"
    android:id="@+id/textViewResponse"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLocation"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewLocation"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewLocation"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:onClick="requestSent"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewResponse"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewResponse"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/wait_response"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewResponse"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewLocation"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewLocation"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/BeginService"
    android:id="@+id/buttonBeginService"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButtonCheck"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:onClick="beginService"
    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:elevation="10px"/>
```

The class for the map it's a fragment:

```
public class Request extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
private FragmentActivity myContext;
Marker marker;
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
Context ctx;
public static final String ARG_REQUEST = "arg_request";

public Request() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.request, container, false);
    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it

    switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()) )
    {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.googleMap);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
            if(mapView!=null)
            {
                map = mapView.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) myContext.getSystemService(myContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                if (location != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
            break;
        default:
    }
    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("onResumeRequest","request");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
    Log.i("onDestroy Request", "request");
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(marker != null){
        marker.remove();
    }
    map.clear();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng));

    marker.setPosition(latLng);

    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_marker));
    marker.setTitle("Tu ubicación");
    marker.showInfoWindow();


    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    //center map on marker and zoom
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

}

And my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String imgDecodableString;
Fragment fragment;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private ImageButton button;
private TextView userNameNavHeader;
private TextView userEmailNavHeader;
private TextView textViewWaitResponse;
private TextView textViewTimeLeft;
private ImageView imageViewWaitResponse;
private Button buttonBService;
private RelativeLayout nav_header;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;
private RequestAccepted ra;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    fragment = new Request();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(Request.ARG_REQUEST, 0);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    fillInfo();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onResumeMainActivity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void fillInfo(){
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
    navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    userNameNavHeader = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userNameTextView);
    userEmailNavHeader = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.userEmailTextView);
    userNameNavHeader.setText(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("name"));
    userEmailNavHeader.setText(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("email"));

    Typeface roboto_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

    userNameNavHeader.setTypeface(roboto_regular);
    userNameNavHeader.setTextSize(16); //32 px
    userEmailNavHeader.setTypeface(roboto_regular);
    userEmailNavHeader.setTextSize(12); //24 px
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return true;
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        //Verificar primero si ya se dio click en el boton comenzar servicio (para poderlo cancelar) Falta!!!

        //cancelTicket (ParseCloud)
        //posteriormente se necesitara hacer un query para poder obtener el ticketId directo de parse

        String ticketId = "B61JHphZPs";

        Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        parameters.put("ticketId", ticketId);

        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("cancelTicket", parameters, new FunctionCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject anwser, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Servicio cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BeginService.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ocurrió un error al cancelar el servicio" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("ERROR",e+"");
                }
            }

        });
    }

    if(id == R.id.refresh){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    Fragment fragment;
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.nav_request) {
        setTitle(R.string.TitleRequest);

        fragment = new Request();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(Request.ARG_REQUEST, 0);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }

    if (id == R.id.nav_history) {
        setTitle(R.string.TitleHistory);

        fragment = new History();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(History.ARG_HISTORY, 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }

    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        setTitle(R.string.TitleProfile);
        fragment = new Profile();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(Profile.ARG_PROFILE, 2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }

    if(id == R.id.nav_sign_out){
        SignOutDialog(this);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewFotoPerfil);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No has elegido una imagen",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Algo salió mal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ally.helper/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.ally.helper/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}


public void openDetails(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void pathGoogle(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.request);
    TextView clientLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);
    String map = "http://maps.google.co.in/maps?daddr=" + clientLocation.getText();
    //from current location remove saddr=32.5224337,-117.0211995
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(map));

        startActivity(intent);
}


public void requestCheckButton(View view){

    button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCheck);
    textViewWaitResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResponse);
    imageViewWaitResponse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewResponse);
    textViewTimeLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTimeLeft);

    ra = new RequestAccepted(this,button,textViewWaitResponse,
            imageViewWaitResponse,textViewTimeLeft);
}

public void requestSent(View view){

    textViewWaitResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResponse);
    imageViewWaitResponse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewResponse);

    String mens = this.getString(R.string.Location)+" ";
    mens += ra.getProgress()+" minutos\n\n\n";
    mens += this.getString(R.string.Remember);
    final AlertDialog.Builder waitingDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    waitingDialog.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.ClientWaiting));
    waitingDialog.setMessage(mens);
    waitingDialog.setPositiveButton(this.getString(R.string.waitingDialogPositiveButton), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            buttonBService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginService);
            buttonBService.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageViewWaitResponse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            textViewWaitResponse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = waitingDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
}

public void beginService(View view){
    //startService (ParseCloud)
    //posteriormente se necesitara hacer un query para poder obtener el serviceId directo de parse

    String serviceId = "KCHWWxCoNP";

    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    parameters.put("serviceId", serviceId);

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("startService", parameters, new FunctionCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject anwser, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Servicio comenzado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BeginService.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ocurrió un error al comenzar el servicio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}

public void saveProfile(View view){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Presionaste guardar perfil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}

// Dialogs
public void SignOutDialog(MainActivity v){

    AlertDialog.Builder signOut = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    signOut.setTitle("");
    signOut.setMessage("¿Estás seguro que deseas cerrar sesión?");
    signOut.setPositiveButton("Cerrar Sesión", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    signOut.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Presionaste Cancelar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    signOut.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Why is `mapView.onResume();` before the super?

Comment: My mistake, sorry I changed it but the problem remains